# Dropdown menu using css/javascript not removing active dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I have a dropdown menu that on click, displays a submenu of list items.
Everything works great except the PARENT 2 submenu, if active, does NOT turn off if I click on the PARENT 3 link with a dropdown.

```
$(function () {
    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function (e) {
        $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
        $('.dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('html').click(function () {
        $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });

});
```

So if I click PARENT 2, the dropdown appears. If I then click PARENT 3, its dropdown also appears (and I need PARENT 2 dropdown to disappear). How to make sure that any menu item clicked removes any instance of an open submenu?

```
<nav>
        <ul class="nav_links">
            <li><a href="#">Parent 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent 2</a>
                <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Child 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Child 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent 3<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Child 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Child 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: You don't have any element with `dropdown` class, which means  `$('.dropdown')` will not match anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was that there isn't any element with the class `dropdown`.

So `$('.dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();` didn't work.

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
    $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('html').click(function() {
    $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="nav_links">
    <li><a href="#">Parent 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent 2</a>
      <ul class="nav-dropdown">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent 3<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="nav-dropdown">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @lowercase Np! Glad I could help!